# Non-recursive way to reverse a list in a purely functional way?

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I'm working in OCaml and need to write a function

```ml
let rev lst = ...
```

which reverses the list `lst` without using recursion.  I don't think I can use iterative methods either, like a for-loop.  And I can't use `List` library functions.  And I can't define some kind of data structure that allows me to interface with the elements in reverse order.  It has to be a very from-bare-OCaml implementation.

Given these constraints I really can't think of any way to do this.  I really don't even know where to start.  The only two things in my bag of tricks, when dealing with arbitrary lists, are recursion and iteration.

Comment: So, you can't use recursion on an inherently recursive data type, and you can't use imperative features. This is a very odd set of requirements.

Comment: I think you're right, i.e., the only choices are to use recursion or iteration. You seem a little less sure that iteration is disallowed than that recursion is disallowed. So the percentage play is to use a while loop and a reference. But maybe there's some missing info that would make things clearer. If this is an assignment (which it sounds like) you might want to ask teacher, prof, TA.

Comment: I _hope_ it's an assignment and no one actually wants to code like this without being forced.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Yeah, it's an assignment, you can see the specs here if you're very curious: https://github.com/umd-cmsc330/fall2022/tree/main/project2a (It's the `reverse` function described there).  I was asked about this by a friend because he can't figure it out and knew I have some OCaml background.  But then I spent a good while on it and I can't figure it out either.  So anyway, I don't think I can directly consult the staff.  But that will be my recommendation to him, I think.

Comment: I read the assigment and for PART 3 you are allowed to write recursive function imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only loophole I can see here is to define *another* function that uses recursion, and then have `rev` use it such that `rev` itself is not recursive. `List.fold_left` is easy enough to reimplement such that your `rev` function also doesn't use any functions from the `List` module. This *should* satisfy the requirements.

```
let rec foldl f i =
  function
  | [] -> i
  | x::xs -> foldl f (f i x) xs
```

And then `rev`:

```
let rev lst = foldl (fun i x -> x::i) [] lst
```

If you feel like being clever, you could reimplement `Fun.flip` as well, and create a `cons` function. Both simple enough.

```
let flip f a b = f b a

let cons a b = a :: b

let rev lst = foldl (flip cons) [] lst
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was kind of thinking. I have to agree, this is an extremely weird set of requirements.